# Write "\" from bash script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, bash, shell, rake-task

I am writing a rake task which contains some bash script,

```
namespace :signup do
  task :install do
   sh "sudo sed -i '/Rails.application.routes.draw do/a \
           mount Signup::Engine, at: '/'' config/routes.rb"  
   end
end
```

But It outputs:
`mount Signup::Engine, at: /`

But I want output as like: `mount Signup::Engine, at: '/'`

Please help me.

Comment: Do you actually want to execute: sh ***-c*** "command"?

Comment: @LeoIzen, yes,  I want execute this.

Comment: Look where the start quotes and the endquotes are in your string. You start a quote at `'/Rails.` and end one at `Engine, at: '`. Then you have a `/` just sitting there, two single quotes `''` which don't do anything, and then the rest of the line.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, there's no way to place a `'` inside of a string made from single quotes. If you want to do that, you have to end the single quote string, place a `'`, and then restart it. This can be done by closing the string with `'`, inserting a `\'`, and then reopening it. Or you could use `"'"` instead of `\'`. Here's some examples:

```
'No! Don'\''t do that!'
'No! Don'"'"'t do that!' 

'mount Signup::Engine, at: '\''/'\'
'mount Signup::Engine, at: '"'"'/'"'"
```

Alternatively, you can use Double Quotes (i.e. `"`) for the string, but keep in mind that escape characters AND variable names are expanded inside double quotes. That would give you:

```
"mount Signup::Engine, at '/'"
```

Comment: sorry, past result :(

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for your sed command to be able to use single quotes inside:

```
sudo sed -i "/Rails.application.routes.draw do/a\\
mount Signup::Engine, at: '/'
" file
```

Or else use `\x27` for single quotes:

```
sudo sed -i '/Rails.application.routes.draw do/a\
mount Signup::Engine, at: \x27/\x27
' file
```

[Working Script Demo](http://ideone.com/CTognN)

Comment: `sh "sudo sed -i '/Rails.application.routes.draw do/a \
           mount Signup::Engine, at: '/'' config/routes.rb"`

Comment: I see in your demo, but I tried with your code but it shows me `mount Signup::Engine, at: /` :(

Comment: I tried in your code from terminal and my rake task, when I run your code from terminal, it gives me correct output, but when I run it from my rake task, it gives me wrong output !!!

Comment: Can you provide me an executable code demo on ideone using ruby so that  I can suggest a fix.

Comment: I am little bit confused, why rake tasks did not execute the command where shell perform correctly, you are right, ideone give correct answer, but in this shell, `sh " "` make fault.